# Non-solenoidal solution of wave equation

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, maxwell-equations

I have found an interesting sentence in my book on electromagnetism:

given the wave equation for electric field in empty space

$$\nabla^2 \vec{E} - \epsilon_0 \mu_0 \frac{d^2 \vec{E}}{dt^2} = 0$$ and similar for magnetic field

these equations are obtained from the third and fourth maxwell equation, however they are not equivalent to the maxwell equation, in fact if we add to $\vec{E}$, that is a solution of the wave equation, an irrotational filed $\vec{E}'$, such that $\nabla \times \vec{E} = 0$, this is also a solution of the wave equation. But in this second case $E + E'$ could be non solenoidal such that his divergenze is not equal to zero anymore.

how it is possible to demonstrate that adding an irrotational component E' we still havea solution of wave eq.?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150662/discussion-on-question-by-adriano-del-vincio-non-solenoidal-solution-of-wave-equ); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding some random $\vec{E}'$ field to $\vec{E}$ such that $\nabla × \vec{E}'=0$ does not guarantee that the new solution is a valid solution to the wave equation.

In order for it to be a solution, we require that $\vec{E}'$ is independantly a solution of the wave equation whilst also being solenoidal. Adding any random solenoidal vector field to a solution does not guarantee it to be a solution of the wave equation.

In addition to this, two fields ,E and B, being solutions of the wave equation does not mean that  they are also  solutions of maxwells equations. The wave equation is implied by the maxwell equations in free space, however the converse is not true. An electromagnetic wave with longitudinal polarisation, E and B out of phase, E and B not being perpendicular are all examples of solutions to the wave equation that do not satisfy the maxwell equations.

Comment: You are right, adding a random irrotational $\vec{E}'$ does not guarantee that $\vec{E} + \vec{E}' $ is still a solution of the maxwell equation. I think that my book wanted to show that the maxwell equation are not equivalent to wave equation, however this sentence is bad formulated

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is as follows: The usual way to derive the wave equation as a consequence of the Maxwell equation is to take the curl of the differential form of Faraday's law, $$\nabla\times\nabla\times\vec E=-\nabla {\partial\vec B\over\partial t}.$$
suppose one were to alter the computation by substituting $\vec E+\vec E^\prime$ for $\vec E$. Since by assumption $\vec E^\prime$ is irrotational, it is ostensibly so that nothing changes in the above equation and the derivation of the wave equation can continue as normal. Since the irrotational field might also be non-solenoidal, then the addition of $\vec E^\prime$ means that one might add any number of sources without accounting for them; something that is patently false as sources must be accounted for in the derivation of the wave equation, hence the usual form of the wave equation with sources:$$\nabla\times\nabla\times\vec E=-g\mu {\partial\vec E\over\partial t}-\epsilon\mu {{\partial}^2\vec E\over\partial t^2}.$$

The author makes this point because they wish to show that the wave equation is not equivalent to the Maxwell equations, i.e. one can dream up fields, willy nilly, that satisfy the wave equation without the field having any physical basis in the Maxwell equations.

One can, however, substitute the Maxwell equations for the fully equivalent wave equation and Lorentz condition, $\nabla\cdot\vec A=-\epsilon\mu{\partial\phi\over\partial t}$, taken together. $\vec A$ is of course the vector potential, and so long as one takes the wave equation together with the Lorentz constraint, then one might proceed with the physics as usual.